# How to cube a number

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, exponentiation

I just started using Python today for my class and one of my problems is cubing a number in Python. I know the way to do it is `x^3`, but that doesn't work in Python. I was just wondering how I would be able to do that.

This is what I tried so far, but as you can see, I keep getting syntax errors:

```
>>> def volume (v) :
    return v^3
volume(4)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: " I know the way to do it is `x^3`, but that doesn't work in Python." That's a contradiction per se. If that doesn't work in Python, it's obviously not the way to do.

Answer (score 20):

Python uses the [`**` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) for exponentiation, not the [`^` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) (which is a bitwise XOR):

```
>>> 3*3*3
27
>>>
>>> 3**3  # This is the same as the above
27
>>>
```

Note however that the syntax error is being raised because there is no newline before `volume(4)`:

```
>>> def volume(v):
...     return v**3
... volume(4)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    volume(4)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> def volume(v):
...     return v**3
...                  # Newline
>>> volume(4)
64
>>>
```

When you are in the interactive interpreter, the newline lets Python know that the definition of function `volume` is finished.

Answer (score 3):

Actually different symbols mean different things in different programming languages. In some languages, `^` means exponent, but in Python, the exponent operator symbol is `**`:

```
>>> 3**3
27
```

The `^` symbol is for the bitwise 'xor' operation:

```
>>> 1^1
0
>>> 1^0
1
```

Read the documentation on the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to see how Python really treats these symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` key twice

```
def volume (v) :
    return v**3
volume(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `**` operator to do exponential calculations.

```
def volume(v)
    return v**3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two asteric's between the number and the power. Ex `2^5` in math is `2**5` in python. You can also do something along the lines of `math.pow(100, 2) =  10000.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this is

```
cube = lambda x: x**3

cube(3)
```

but one another solution be like which result in the same

```
cube = lambda x: x*x**2

cube(3)
```

one another alter solution be like

```
math.pow(3,3)
```

all will return the cube of number 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def volume(v):
    result = v * v * v
    return result


print("enter a number to be cubed: ")
print(volume(int(input())))
```

or

```
def volume(v):
    result = v ** 3
    return result


print("enter a number to be cubed: ")
print(volume(int(input())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is attempting to use `^` as the exponentiation operator, but you should be using the `**` operator.  For example:

```
>>> def volume (v) :
...   return v ** 3
...
>>> volume(4)
64
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this with using a simple `print` function, you can calculate the cube by using `**` operators

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

print(a**3)
print(b**3)
```